# Angular ui-router cannot resolve $resource results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, resolve

In one of my UI-router states, I have the following link `'/users'`, which points to a page that shows a list of users. Below is the code I wrote to resolve the list of users by using a $resource call, however, the data doesn't seem resolved when the page is loaded:

```
.state('users', {
                    url: '/users',
                    templateUrl: '/assets/angularApp/partials/users.html',
                    controller: 'UserListCtrl as vm',
                    resolve: {

                        users: function ($resource) {

                            return $resource('http://localhost:8080/api/users').query().$promise.then(function(data) {
                                return data;
                            });
                        }
                    }


                })
```

In the **UserListCtrl**, I have the following to assign the resolved users to vm.users so that the users can be displayed on the partial page:

```
function UserListCtrl($log, users) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.users = users;
}
```

The page, however, only displays a few empty rows without any data filled in. So I think the `resolve` is not working properly on my url `/users`, could anyone spot where might be problematic? Thanks

Comment: what does your response looks like?

Comment: Response is an array of Jason

Comment: if you inspect your scope what value does vm.users have?

Comment: vm.users shows 'undefined'

Comment: can you place a line break in your  "return data" line inside the resolve and inspect the function arguments?

Answer (score 5):

Change it to:

```
users: function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:8080/api/users').query().$promise;
}
```

Because that way you're returning the promise, and by using then(...), you're resolving the promise within and just returning data thus it won't pass it to the controller because it's returning them after the controller has loaded.

Comment: Giving an explanation to why your answer works will help your readers learn.

Comment: I had to be quick at the time as was quite busy, but now there's the explanation on how I understand it and the reason why I said change it to that. But that's a good food for thought, thanks :)

Comment: This is late coming to this question, but then how do we deal with data processing beore it gets passed on? For example If i wanted to intercept an error in the request and return a default value instead

Comment: Sorry for the late response, you have to return a promise, so you could use var someVar = $q.defer; and make the request, then on success do someVar.resolve(data); and return someVar.promise; for users,

users: function ($resource, $q) {
 var someVar = $q.defer();
 $resource('http://localhost:8080/api/users').query().$promise.then(function(data) { 
    // do something with the data
   someVar.resolve(data);
});

return someVar.promise;
}

Answer (score 0):

Using `$q` service will help you

```
var userVal = $resource('http://localhost:8080/api/users').query()
retrun $q.resolve(userVal.$promise).then(function(r){ return r;});
```

Inside you controller, you are good to go

```
vm.users = users
```

Comment: `$q` service that helps you run functions asynchronously, and use their return values (or exceptions) when they are done processing.
[link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)