# Why can I not chain promises in a route 'resolve'?

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-routing

I am trying to chain the promise that fetches 'dtaDashboard' to use a value from the fetched dashboard, to execute a second call. For some reason the promise chain does not seem to work inside a 'resolve'. Why not?

```
state('uploadServiceTxData', {
        url: '/dashboard/:id/upload',
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard-upload.html',
        controller: 'DashboardUploadController',
        resolve: {
            dtaRefData: function(RefDataService) {
                return RefDataService.getRefData();
            },
            dtaDashboard: function(DashboardService, $stateParams) {
                return DashboardService.get({ id: $stateParams.id });
            },
            dtaUploads: function(TransactionSummaryUploadService, dtaDashboard, $q) {
                return dtaDashboard.then(function(dashboard) { return TransactionSummaryUploadService.findByExample({ service: dashboard.service.name }) });
            }
        }
    });
```

---

Some more information on the code above. The functions on the DashboardSerivce and TransactionSummaryUploadService, are implemented with $resource. So "get" and "findByExample" use $resource to make REST calls.

Comment: I haven't tried to replicate  your issue yet but why don't you just combine both `dtaDashboard` and `dtaUploads` into one resolve?  At the end of the promise chain you can return an object with both the the dashboard and the other thing that you want.

Comment: I think that is what I will do. Note though that the question is "why" does this not work.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by saying that it doesn't work?  Is there an error being thrown? Is it never actually resolving? Are you getting a different type of object than you expect?

Comment: Its never resolving. The route fails to complete and I get a blank screen. If I comment out the contents of the 'dtaUploads' resolve function, then it will proceed and render the route.

Comment: This question is also helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28533775/angular-ui-router-cannot-resolve-resource-results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it did not work is that the services were implemented with $resource. The methods of $resource do not return promises, they return an object which contains a promise, and some other things. To get to the promise itself, I needed to use dtaDashboard.$promise.

So code like this works:

```
dtaDashboard: function(DashboardService, $stateParams) {
    return DashboardService.get({ id: $stateParams.id });
},
dtaUploads: function(dtaDashboard) {
    dtaDashboard.$promise.then(function(result) { ... /* result contains the data now. */ });
}
```

---

return DashboardService.get({ id: $stateParams.id });

Does not return the promise from the $resource service, it returns an object containing the promise (and eventually the data); that object is resolved, but not the promise it contains. To ensure that the route resolves to the data, this can be done instead:

```
dtaDashboard: function(DashboardService, $stateParams) {
    return DashboardService.get({ id: $stateParams.id }).$promise;
}
```

Now dtaDashboard will be fully resolved to the data wherever it is injected.

Answer (score 2):

You are very close.

`dtaDashboard` has already been resolved when it's injected into `datUploads`. So you use the resolved result (meaning it's no longer a promise).

```
state('uploadServiceTxData', {
    url: '/dashboard/:id/upload',
    templateUrl: 'views/dashboard-upload.html',
    controller: 'DashboardUploadController',
    resolve: {
        dtaRefData: function(RefDataService) {
            return RefDataService.getRefData();
        },
        dtaDashboard: function(DashboardService, $stateParams) {
            return DashboardService.get({ id: $stateParams.id });
        },
        dtaUploads: function(TransactionSummaryUploadService, dtaDashboard, $q) {
            return TransactionSummaryUploadService.findByExample({ service: dtaDashboard.service.name });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: No, 'dtaDashboard' has not been resolved by then. 'dtaDashboard.service' is undefined.

Comment: Go read the ui-router documentation. Promises are always resolved before they are injected. If any promise in a resolve is rejected the state change is aborted. The fact that `dtaDashboard.service` is undefined has nothing to do with ui-router.

Comment: If you look at the console and see the result when you click on "Show List" within "Route 1" at the following link, then you can see that it is actually working like @ThinkingMedia described.  If you are getting an undefined, it is because your response doesn't have the service object or there is something else going wrong.  See working example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ncZ83v?p=preview

Comment: I don't understand, because if I do this: dtaUploads: function(dtaDashboard) { console.log(dtaDashboard); }. Then I get this on the console: "Resource {$promise: Promise, $resolved: false}". Once the promise is resolved, then service and its name is defined. It really does look like dtaDashboard is not resolved yet...?

Comment: @ThinkingMedia, my bad for saying it has not been resolved, it has, its just that I was using $resource, which returns an object containing a promise, not a promise itself.

Comment: @JoseM, thanks for taking the time to create a plnkr based on my code. Most helpful.

Comment: @user2800708 oh you're using $resource. That's different. It uses lazy loading for data. To get it to work with resolve you have to do this `return DashboardService.get(..).$promise`.