# $resource resolve in ui-router error catching don't fail state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-resource

I am running a ui-router with a resolve in it, and the resolved data looks like this:

```
myService: "myService"
items: function(myService){
                var promise = myService.resource.query().$promise;
                return promise;
            }
```

However, if this promise fails, the entire state is aborted and $stateChangeError is thrown. I want to instead of aborting the whole state, simply set the value of items to be a default value and continue on to the state. The only solution I was able to find seems like a hack:

```
myService: "myService",
items: ['myService', '$q', function(myService, $q) {
                //return []
                defObj = $q.defer();
                var promise = myService.resource.query().$promise;
                promise.then(function(data) {
                    defObj.resolve(data);
                },function(error) {
                    defObj.resolve([{title: "sorry, could not load"}]);
                })
                return defObj.promise;
            }]
```

With this, regardless of whether the request fails the promise will resolve and the state will continue on. Are there any simpler solutions to this problem?

If it matters, I am using this within a resolve because the information affects the flow of the page and I don't want it to load the page until the data is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Simplified problem :

```
myService: "myService"
items: function(myService){
   return myService.resource.query();
}
```

Solution :

```
myService: "myService"
items: function(myService){
   return myService.resource.query()
     .then(function(data) {
        return data;
      }, function() {
         return [{title: "sorry, could not load"}];
      });
}
```

EDIT: 
Above code is for simple service call returning a Promise.

For the $ressource api :
From this code example from the docs :

```
User.get({userId:123})
    .$promise.then(function(user) {
      $scope.user = user;
    });
```

I guess you could simplify to this :

```
myService: "myService",
items: ['myService', function(myService) {
              return myService.resource.query().$promise
                .then(function(data) {
                    return data;
                },function(error) {
                    return [{title: "sorry, could not load"}];
                });
            }]
```

And no, it's not good to surround a promise in a defered service (`$q`). Except if you have multiple Promises.

Comment: I believe using the $promise is mandatory. As in for the resolve to work properly in the router it has to be fed a $promise not just the resource action

Comment: http://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-resolve-angularjs-resources-with-ui-router/ for an explanation on  why the $promise is necessary

Comment: I thought query was a service you wrote, not the angular ressource API

Comment: This example is when using regular Promise calling a custom service. I see no problem in your code. If it works with your API

Comment: When you say my code do you mean the second code snippet? Do you think surrounding the resource call (which has a $q within it) with another $q is stylistically okay?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28533775/angular-ui-router-cannot-resolve-resource-results explains why using then() ruins the point of returning a $promise to the resolve

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it.... The key is adding an interceptor with a responseError function into the resource method definition

```
 "query": {
            method: "GET",
            isArray: true,
            /*This will prevent the promise from being rejected even on fail*/
            interceptor: {
                responseError: function() { 
                    return [{title: "Sorry, could not load"}];
                }
            }

        }
```